# Fedora 36 (KDE) color management is broken

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, color-profiles

Currently I am trying to start using color management on my desktop again. Back in 2016 I bought a Spyder 5, I had it all running back then, but now it seems to be broken. Since most color/photo related software works under windows, I installed [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net/) there. This way I generated a calibration (.icm-File) file for both monitors (Dell P2715Q).

So far so good, but when I try to use this .icm-File on my main Fedora 36 the Devices field in the color correction setting is empty (apart from a printer) as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQCEO.png).
The next thing (after some research) is to run `colormgr get-devices` which also only shows the printer (to keep this post short I don't list the result here), which fits the screenshot.

Next I had a look at `systemctl status colord.service` which gives a `failed to get edid data: EDID length is too small` warning, which (thanks to `journalctl -u colord` and `dnf history`) I know is only present since the last `system-upgrade upgrade`. On my Backup Fedora the EDID warning is not present, but `colormgr get-devices` is still empty, which leads me to believe that these things are separate issues. On my Laptop Fedora `colormgr get-devices` works just fine. A web search brings up a lot of similar topics from around 2012 to 2015 but all without a satisfying solution.

Next I thought about using `dispwin` to set the calibration with a startscript, which works but has another problem. The way it is done [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69230/how-to-install-colour-profile-screen-device-not-listed) only tests out a .icm-File and does not install it system wide (like recommend [here](https://argyllcms.com/doc/Scenarios.html#PM5)). This does not seem to be a big issue at the first glance, but this leads to the screen only being calibrated but the actual profiling can't be done since all color correctet applications (like Gimp or Geeqie) are set to use the system default profile and I'd like to keep it this way. But I can't just install/load the profile with `dispwin -I`/`dispwin -L` since `dispwin -V` only shows `Dispwin: Error - No calibration/profile provided to verify against`, which is concise with the color correction setting in the Fedora setting (see screenshot above), there I can't load a new profile either. So this is a death end too.

In conclusion: I have two problems with color management at the moment:

1. My device list is empty
2. I can't install new profiles

Do you have any idea how to fix these issues or where would be the best place to file a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found and fixed my problem: In the `/home/user/.config/kded5rc` file I had to set

```
[Module-colord]
autoload=true
```

which was initially set to `false`.
I have no idea how it got disabled, but now it works.